# Unable to include bootstrap in React-app when installing it globally

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm, npm-install

I installed `bootstrap` using `npm i -g bootstrap` and trying to include `bootstrap` in a **React-app** as `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`.

However, it is throwing an error.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in '/home/username/nodeProjects/react-app/src'
```

But when I actually install it locally as `npm i bootstrap` and import it as `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`, it is working as expected.

Is there any different approach to import `npm` packages when they are installed **globally** and **locally** or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: why you need bootstrap globally? its required dependency

Comment: I would  assume that normally the import of a local package searches for a package inside of the local node_modules directory only (not proved). I am not sure that you are really need to install bootstrap globally, because it's better to keep your system clean and setup dependencies per project only

Comment: packages that are installed global not recorded in the package.json file so when you move to production and run npm i bootstrap will not be installed for you and will case problem

Comment: Ok. But don't you think that it should be working like all other `global` modules work when importing?

Comment: global packages have a different location you need to include that path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `npm install -g bootstrap` this will install bootstrap globally.

Then you can use `npm link <global-package>` so in your case `npm link bootstrap` to create a local link to a package already installed globally. (Caveat: The OS must support symlinks.)

To see you all global packages and its location:

```
npm list -g
```

Use `npm list -g | head -n 1` for truncated output showing just the path.

The npm install command does not support installing a module both globally and save it to the package.json in one step.

There is, however, a way to install a module globally indirectly. The package.json supports a preinstall property like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm install -g bootstrap"
}
```

As soon as you execute npm install, bootstrap will be installed globally. Please note that your current user then needs permission to write to your global node module directory.